# Trigger dont exceed value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
JOBS (id_job, startdate, enddate, hours_job_per_employee)
EMPLOYEE (id_employe, id_job, startdate, enddate)
```

And for example:

```
JOB:

   id_job    startdate    enddate    hours_job_per_employee
------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     02/05/2012   04/08/2013         1221
      2     04/07/2014   12/12/2016         1825


EMPLOYEE:

id_employee  id_job       startdate      enddate  
------------------------------------------------------------------
      1         1         02/05/2012   06/06/2012
      1         1         01/01/2013   02/05/2013
      2         1         02/08/2014   04/09/2014
      1         2         03/09/2014   04/04/2015
```

I have to check with a trigger if for each employee, hours per week don't exceed 70. Each employee can be appear in several times on EMPLOYEE with the same job or another.

I'm using oracle

I tried this but not works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on employee
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  count NUMBER;
  firstdate DATE;
  days NUMBER;
  hoursday NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT startdate INTO firstdate FROM employee WHERE rownum=1 AND id_employee= :NEW.id_employee ORDER BY startdate;

  SELECT to_number(to_char(enddate,'J')-to_char(firstdate,'J')) INTO days FROM employee WHERE rownum=1 AND id_employee= :NEW.id_employee ORDER BY startdate DESC; 
                                                                                                            AND m.enddate > n.enddate;

FOR i IN 0..days LOOP
   count:=0;
FOR j IN 0..6 LOOP
  hoursday:=0;
  SELECT sum(p.hours_job_per_employee//7*to_number(to_char(enddate,'J')-to_char(startdate,'J')))) INTO hoursday FROM 
    job p JOIN employee m ON (p.id_job=m.id_job) 
    WHERE :NEW.id_employee= m.id_employee AND to_char(firstdate,'J')+1 > to_char(m.startdate,'J') AND to_char(firstdate,'J')+1 < to_char(m.enddate,'J')
    ORDER BY m.startdate;
    firstdate := to_date(firstdate+1,'DD-MM-YY');
    count := count+hoursday;
  END LOOP;
  IF count>70 THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'FAIL'); END IF;
END LOOP;
END TRIG1;
/
```

But not run correctly..Why? Sends me my error when should not give it

Comment: I know you are not asking for it, but this is a very good example for not using triggers. It is totally not encouraging for people to not be able to enter their time sheets. Such an application requires the person to lie about worktime. It is much better to allow them to enter the time and if you still need to address it have a weekly report to the user (and or her manager) to make sure it is dealt with.

Comment: Define "a week".  Do you want to measure, say, from Monday - Sunday?  Sunday - Saturday?  Any consecutive 7 day period?  Why do you need to use a trigger?  In a real application, I might be editing multiple rows and you'd need to do the validation against the end result not for each row.  It's possible to do that with multiple triggers, a package, and a collection, but it's not very elegant.  It would generally make more sense to implement the check later in the application.

Comment: I define a week as 7 day period from Monday to Sunday. I would like to use a trigger because is that I am learning

Comment: I have created a trigger which I think makes what I want, but when I insert a row that not shouldn't gives me my application error, it gives me it..What can I do?